# Monit showing 0 hosts connected

Tags: monit

I am new to Monit. I have one VM and am trying to run M/Monit and Monit on the same server.
I downloaded the binary for both and ran both processes.

All M/Monit configs are default and I have not changed anything.
As for Monit, I have kept the standard configs too.

My server IP address is : 142.133.142.122

On the client config,

```
set httpd port 2812 and
use address localhost  # only accept connection from localhost
allow localhost        # allow localhost to connect to the server and
allow admin:monit      # require user 'admin' with password 'monit'
```

I am starting the client with this config.

But when I access the GUI, I do not see any host connected.

Status command says

```
[root@Redhat6664x bin]# ./monit status
Monit uptime: 18m
System 'Redhat6664x'
status                       Not monitored
monitoring status            Not monitored
monitoring mode              active
on reboot                    start
data collected               Sun, 12 Jun 2016 11:03:09
```

The processes show

```
[root@Redhat6664x bin]# ps -ef | grep monit
root     20804     1  0 11:07 ?        00:00:00 ./mmonit
root     20907     1  0 11:23 ?        00:00:00 ./monit -c ../conf/monitrc
root     20910 20207  0 11:23 pts/1    00:00:00 grep monit
```

Is there some configuration I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to specify your M/Monit host in the Monit configuration.

`set mmonit http://monit:password@142.133.142.122:8080/collector`